# Excel, Array Formulas, N/A outside of range, and ROW()

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have a problem with ROW() in an array formula in Excel 2013.

Example:

I make a named range, called 'input', say 4 cells wide and 10 high. Then I make an array formula `=ROW(input)` one cell wide, 15 cells high.

I get 10 numbers - the first is the first row of input, and the rest count up from that, and then 5 #N/A follow. This is as it should be.

If instead of `=ROW(input)` I try one of the following:

```
=IFERROR(ROW(input),"x")
```

or

```
=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),"x",ROW(input))
```

to catch the #N/As then what I expect to see is ten numbers, and then five x's. Instead I still see ten numbers and then five #N/As.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? I want to get ten numbers, and then five x's.

And of lesser importance but just for curiosity (or in case it comes up in another case), why does this happen?

Why do I want to do this? It's part of a larger formula that I have simplified for this question.

Comment: If I was in VBA then I could probably check the size of the input table, and then ensure that the current row did not exceed it. But I'm not in VBA.

Comment: Forgive me, but the way you've structured your question is so long and complex that I feel the overall point of what you're asking may have become lost. It appears as if you're wanting to simply add a clause to your array formula such that, in rows to which you copy that formula beyond the expected number of returns, something other than an error is returned. However, if this were the case then: a) it's not at all clear from your description and b) the error in such cases would not (normally) be #N/A but rather #NUM!. Also, it's not clear why you're including INDEX's 4th parameter here (?)

Comment: I also don't understand these clauses you're attempting with =IFERROR(ROW(input) or =IF(ISNA(ROW(input)). Assuming input is simply a range reference to some table or other, how can a row number ever be an error? (Unless the row reference of the value being passed at some point exceeds 1048576, of course.)

Comment: Question simplified. Apologies. Why do I always seem to end up at stackoverflow when I have the flu? :(

Comment: If that's still not clear, let me know and I'll try again to clarify. @XOR LX, In the case of the plain `=ROW(input)` the #N/A is because the array formula goes beyond the array, and so excel 'extends the array' with #N/A, as I understand it. why I get #N/A instead of #NUM! or indeed 'x' in the other cases is the reason for the question! And why IFERROR()? Because it catches #N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL! and at this point I want to catch anything, I just want it to work! :(

Comment: Much clearer! Your original post did not make it clear that the array in question was a MULTI-CELL array! Your error here is because, beyond the tenth row over which this array is processed, there is simply no equivalent 11th, 12th member in your set to process. But, with multi-cell array formulas such as this, this is not an #N/A which can be "resolved" as such - there will never be an 11th row when you are processing a 10-row range. Are you not able to use a SINGLE-CELL array formula, which, dragged down, would give the equivalent results? Then you COULD use some form of IFERROR statement.

Comment: 'with multi-cell array formulas such as this, this is not an #N/A which can be "resolved" as such' - but why? I mean, I guess I could accept the answer 'because', it might be a quirk of Excel's code, but is there a clearer reason for that? Strangely, if I have `=ISNA(B15)` where B15 is one of the #N/As from my example of `=ROW(input)` then it shows TRUE, so clearly the #N/A can be resolved from a **different** cell. And I've seen other cases of #N/A in array formulas fixed using IFERROR() etc, some mine, others eg http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/528017-ignore-n-array-formula.html

Comment: For a single cell array, I'm doubtful what I need can be done with that, though I could be wrong. I'm looking to filter a named range 6 columns wide, unknown length long, into another table, the filtering done by date (one of the columns). That works fine, but as is often the case, when going beyond the available table rows you get an #N/A and I'm trying to catch and handle that... the part of the formula that is throwing the #N/A is the ROW(). If you want, I could post my full formula here for you to look over.

Comment: I don't know of anything which can be achieved using a multi-cell array formula which can't also be achieved using a series of single-cell array formulas. I'm not sure what you mean by "filter" a named range, either. Perhaps you should either amend this post or start a new one, in which you veer away from your query re the ROW function and multi-cell array formulas and instead post a small, reduced dataset with dummy data together with your expected results.

Comment: To answer your earlier query, that's simply the way multi-cell array formulas are designed. And you being able to "resolve" the #N/A from a different cell is a moot point: as I stated, you will always receive this error-type in cells in the range over which you apply the array which exceed the dimensions of the range reference specified. Why is this so hard to accept? Why SHOULD you be able to reference a cell which, for all intents and purposes, doesn't exist? Equally, I can't write =INDEX(A1:A10,11), and rightly so, in my opinion.

Comment: @XOR LX. You do **not** always receive that error-type 'in cells [...] which exceed the dimensions of the range reference specified'. Try this: Create a named range 5 cells high. Create several array formulae 10 cells high, the first with `=ROW(input)`, the second with `=ISNA(ROW(input))`, the third with `=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),"YES","NO")`.  At least in my version of Excel 2010 Professional, the first and third have #N/As, but the second does NOT. Why does the addition of an IF() around something that returns TRUE and FALSE break it?

Comment: Sincere apologies. That's a novel, and very interesting, example. I have attempted an explanation below.

Comment: No worries - I'm just glad to have someone thinking about this at all. I appreciate your time, and the graciousness of your last comment just adds to that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, in such clauses, Excel gives precedence to the artificial expansion of the reference to match that of the worksheet range selected (which it will always do by filling with #N/As) over first resolving the IF clause over the array.

So, whereas "normally" (e.g in a single-cell array formula), e.g.:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),"YES","NO"))
```

would, effectively, coerce Excel into expanding the single *value_if_true* and *value_if_false* parameters of the IF function into syntactically-appropriate arrays of those values, viz:

```
=SUM(IF({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE},{"YES","YES","YES","YES","YES"},{"NO","NO","NO","NO","NO"}))
```

i.e.:

```
=SUM({"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO"})
```

with multi-cell array formulas, e.g. your:

```
=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),"YES","NO")
```

entered over a 10-cell range, is NOT first resolved thus:

```
=IF(ISNA({1;2;3;4;5;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A}),{"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES"},{"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO"})
```

(In which the the *value_if_true* and *value_if_false* parameters are first re-dimensioned in accordance with the dimension of the worksheet range in which the array is being entered.)

i.e.:

```
=IF({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE},{"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES"},{"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO"})
```

i.e.:

```
={"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES"}
```

but rather as:

```
=IF(ISNA({1;2;3;4;5;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A}),{"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A},{"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A})
```

(The *value_if_true* and *value_if_false* parameters first being re-dimensioned in accordance rather with the dimensions of the Named Range *input*.)

i.e.:

```
=IF({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE},{"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";"YES";#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A},{"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A})
```

i.e.:

```
{"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";"NO";#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A}
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Regards

Comment: Hmm... It's a little late in my night here so my thinking is not 100%, but... if that were the case, could we not just use `=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),{"Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"},{"N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N"})` ? Note that there are only 8 cases covered (8 "Y's and "N"s), to show up any other strange results (eg for some **other** obscure reason all 10 worked), but I've also tried it with 10 cases covered. I still get 5 good answers, and 5 #N/As. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A nice try, though I don't believe that YOU'RE allowed to artificially expand the ranges! Perhaps my attempt at explaining wasn't quite correct: put another way, Excel has already determined that the other, extraneous elements in that array are invalid. I imagine your additional "N"s and "Y"s would, effectively, be "replaced" with "#N/A"s here (for want of a better definition). Though I confess that we could do with a representative from Microsoft here to explain this one!

Comment: OK, follow up, I tried creating two named ranges, each 10 cells tall, one with each cell containing a 'Y' called Ys, one with each cell containing an 'N' called Ns. I then made an array formula 10 tall with `=IF(I5:I14,Ys,Ns)` and that worked fine. Shortening Ys and Ns to 8 high also produced the expected response. So it looks like your answer is right and I just don't get arrays yet (I tried creating an array formula 10 high with `={"y","y","y","y","y","N","N","N","N","N"}` and just got all Ys, which I don't get. Time to do some reading!

Comment: Yeah, I can see that (probably) the single "Y" or "N" is artificially expanded to be the size of the output (10 high), but I don't get why the limit on valid values ("Y"s and "N"s) is set at the size of the input (5 high) and the rest filled with #N/As. Since it's coming from a single value you would expect it either to fill with 1 "Y" and 9 #N/As, or all 10 "Y"s. Seems like you've nailed the problem, and it hints at a solution (using my correctly sized named range, or one larger than needed), but I'm curious as to the thinking behind it from Microsoft. As you say, we need an MS explanation.

Comment: I'm going to hold off on marking it as the answer in case further research by you pins it down further, but I think so far you've got it pretty close to an answer...

Comment: Re your attempt with {"y","y","y","y","y","N","N","N","N","N"}, you're using commas, which in Excel represent column-separators! Try ={"y";"y";"y";"y";"y";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N"} instead. Alternatively, array-enter your version over a 1-row-by-10-column array. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks - habits of a different language! That said, I tried `=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),{"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y";"Y"},{"N";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N";"N"})` and it still gave me five #N/As

Comment: Of course! That hasn't changed. Like I said, YOU can't re-dimension that range!

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. 6 comments above, I thought I'd tested with `=IF(ISNA(ROW(input)),YS,NS)` and it worked fine, instead I tested with `=IF(I5:I14,Ys,Ns)` and that worked fine (of course)! I even wrote the latter in my comment above. I think I'll get some sleep and come back at this fresh. Thanks again, catch you when my brain works!

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! And I'll try to look into some more myself.