# replace #N/A with blank when applying array formula beyond its range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601417/iferrorformula-passing-n-a-instead-of) and similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855683/array-returning-n-a-for-some-elements-want-blank) and after some more reading [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285970/excel-array-formulas-n-a-outside-of-range-and-row)

Hopefully I do not over simplify this question.  When applying the following formula using CSE to make it an array to the range A1:A7 how can you get #N/A to display as ""?

```
=IFERROR(ROW(A1:A5),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two columns, in the first column put your array formula, in the second column write your "iserror" using "if", suppose if your array formula is in A2, write the following formula in B2.

=IF(iserror(A2),"",A2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying IFNA() over your values. For example:

```
=VSTACK({1,2,3},{4,5})
```

returns:

```
1   2   3
4   5   #N/A
```

But:

```
=IFNA(VSTACK({1,2,3},{4,5}),"")
```

returns:

```
1   2   3
4   5
```